# What is the `zero` value for time.Time in Go?

Tags: time, go, null

In an error condition, I tried to return `nil`, which throws the error:

```
cannot use nil as type time.Time in return argument
```

What is the `zero` value for `time.Time`?

Comment: And you can use `IsZero()` to detect the zero time.

Comment: Usually, when I want to return `nil` to make evidence no value has been set, I use pointers as return values in function signature.

Answer (score 296, accepted):

Invoking an empty `time.Time` struct literal will return Go's zero date. Thus, for the following print statement:

```
fmt.Println(time.Time{})
```

The output is:

```
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

For the sake of completeness, the [official documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) explicitly states:

> The zero value of type Time is January 1, year 1, 00:00:00.000000000 UTC.

Comment: "Passing no arguments" makes it sound like a function call. It's a struct literal with no fields specified. X{} is the zero value of the struct X for any X.

Comment: @RussCox I don't think that's true. In my case, I have a field of time.Time in my struct which has 'omitempty' attribute. If I don't set that value, it gets automatically set to 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC instead of being ignored.

Comment: @GauravOjha See [Golang JSON omitempty With time.Time Field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643815/golang-json-omitempty-with-time-time-field/32646035#32646035).

Comment: Marty! We have to go back!

Answer (score 449):

You should use the [`Time.IsZero()`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.IsZero) function instead:

```
func (Time) IsZero
```

or

```
func (t Time) IsZero() bool
```

> IsZero reports whether t represents the zero time instant, January 1, year 1, 00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: Indeed, if comparing whether the given value for time is nil or not, this is what should actually be used.

Comment: While this is correct answer for comparison, the OP did not ask about comparison, but rather how to initialize zero value. Accepted answer is correct.

Answer (score 8):

The zero value for time.Time is `0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC`  See http://play.golang.org/p/vTidOlmb9P

Answer (score 3):

Tested on Go v1.18

The default value for `time.Time` is:

```bash
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Checking with `IsZero()` function is a clean way.

```golang
var zeroTime time.Time

if zeroTime.IsZero() {
    // do something when zero
}
```