# JSON omitempty With time.Time Field

Tags: json, go, time, struct

Trying to json Marshal a struct that contains 2 time fields. But I only want the field to come through if it has a time value. So I'm using `json:",omitempty"` but it's not working.

What can I set the Date value to so json.Marshal will treat it like an empty (zero) value and not include it in the json string?

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/QJwh7yBJlo

**Actual Outcome:**

> {"Timestamp":"2015-09-18T00:00:00Z","Date":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"}

***Desired Outcome:***

> {"Timestamp":"2015-09-18T00:00:00Z"}

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    Timestamp time.Time `json:",omitempty"`
    Date      time.Time `json:",omitempty"`
    Field     string    `json:",omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    ms := MyStruct{
        Timestamp: time.Date(2015, 9, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC),
        Field:     "",
    }

    bb, err := json.Marshal(ms)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(bb))
}
```

Comment: The feature [does not work with time.Time](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/1fd78e1f600d10475b85381427bda9f14f86e0f0/src/encoding/json/encode.go#L278-L294).

Comment: Probably the easiest way to your goal would be to let MyStruct implement http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler.

Comment: Good to know and good advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 151, accepted):

The `omitempty` tag option does not work with `time.Time` as it is a `struct`. There is a "zero" value for structs, but that is a struct value where all fields have their zero values. This is a "valid" value, so it is not treated as "empty".

But by simply changing it to a pointer: `*time.Time`, it will work (`nil` pointers are treated as "empty" for json marshaling/unmarshaling). So no need to write custom [`Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) in this case:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Timestamp *time.Time `json:",omitempty"`
    Date      *time.Time `json:",omitempty"`
    Field     string     `json:",omitempty"`
}
```

Using it:

```
ts := time.Date(2015, 9, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
ms := MyStruct{
    Timestamp: &ts,
    Field:     "",
}
```

Output (as desired):

```
{"Timestamp":"2015-09-18T00:00:00Z"}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/ahfIEsO80A).

If you can't or don't want to change it to a pointer, you can still achieve what you want by implementing a custom [`Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) and [`Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler). If you do so, you can use the [`Time.IsZero()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.IsZero) method to decide if a `time.Time` value is the zero value.

Answer (score 9):

You may define you self Time type for custom marshal format, and use it everywhere instead `time.Time`

https://play.golang.org/p/C8nIR1uZAok

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type MyTime struct {
    *time.Time
}

func (t MyTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(t.Format("\"" + time.RFC3339 + "\"")), nil
}

// UnmarshalJSON implements the json.Unmarshaler interface.
// The time is expected to be a quoted string in RFC 3339 format.
func (t *MyTime) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) (err error) {

    // by convention, unmarshalers implement UnmarshalJSON([]byte("null")) as a no-op.
    if bytes.Equal(data, []byte("null")) {
        return nil
    }

    // Fractional seconds are handled implicitly by Parse.
    tt, err := time.Parse("\""+time.RFC3339+"\"", string(data))
    *t = MyTime{&tt}
    return
}

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    d, err := json.Marshal(MyTime{&t})
    fmt.Println(string(d), err)
    var mt MyTime
    json.Unmarshal(d, &mt)
    fmt.Println(mt)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As a follow up to icza's answer here is a custom marshaller that omits an empty date field but keeps the rest of the fields unchanged.

```
func (ms *MyStruct) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type Alias MyStruct
    if ms.Timestamp.IsZero() {
        return json.Marshal(&struct {
            Timestamp int64 `json:",omitempty"`
            *Alias
        }{
            Timestamp: 0,
            Alias:     (*Alias)(ms),
        })
    } else {
        return json.Marshal(&struct {
            *Alias
        }{
            Alias: (*Alias)(ms),
        })
    }
}
```

This borrows from http://choly.ca/post/go-json-marshalling/

The OPs case has two time fields which would make it much more complicated. (you'd have to check for neither, either and both being empty!)

There may be better ways to achieve this, so comments are welcome.