# How search in mongo with using custom structure?

Tags: mongodb, go, struct, default-value

How to ignore the default values of the `time` field in the query?
Because they are set in `0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC`, I can not find the right document

```
// User model
type User struct {
    Mail      string        `json:"mail" bson:"mail,omitempty"`
    Password  string        `json:"password" bson:"password,omitempty"`
    CreatedAt time.Time     `json:"created_at" bson:"created_at,omitempty"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time     `json:"updated_at" bson:"updated_at,omitempty"`
}
```

Example https://play.golang.org/p/P2P30PPtl0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) is a struct type, and its [zero](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) value is a valid time value and is not considered "empty". So in case of `time.Time` if you need to differentiate between the [zero](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) and empty values, use a pointer to it instead, that is `*time.Time`. The `nil` pointer value will be the *empty* value, and any non-`nil` pointer values will denote non-empty time values.

```
type User struct {
    Mail      string     `json:"mail" bson:"mail,omitempty"`
    Password  string     `json:"password" bson:"password,omitempty"`
    CreatedAt *time.Time `json:"created_at" bson:"created_at,omitempty"`
    UpdatedAt *time.Time `json:"updated_at" bson:"updated_at,omitempty"`
}
```

See related question: [Golang JSON omitempty With time.Time Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643815/golang-json-omitempty-with-time-time-field/32646035#32646035)