# sql: Scan error on column index 2, name "created_on": converting driver.Value type time.Time

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

The way I query：

```
package models

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    //postgres dv
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"

    "ginstatus/pkg/setting"
)

var db *gorm.DB

type Model struct {
    ID         int `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id"`
    CreatedOn  int `json:"created_on"`
    ModifiedOn int `json:"modified_on"`
}

func init() {
    var (
        err                                                     error
        dbType, dbName, user, password, host, port, tablePrefix string
    )

    sec, err := setting.Cfg.GetSection("database")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(2, "Fail to get section 'database': %v", err)
    }

    dbType = sec.Key("TYPE").String()
    dbName = sec.Key("NAME").String()
    user = sec.Key("USER").String()
    password = sec.Key("PASSWORD").String()
    host = sec.Key("HOST").String()
    port = sec.Key("PORT").String()
    tablePrefix = sec.Key("TABLE_PREFIX").String()

    db, err = gorm.Open(dbType, fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s dbname=%s password=%s",
        host,
        port,
        user,
        dbName,
        password))
    // db, err = gorm.Open("postgres", "host=192.168.2.200 port=5433 user=czxsql dbname=go_blog password=123456")

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    //##############################
    // db.LogMode(true)
    //##############################

    gorm.DefaultTableNameHandler = func(db *gorm.DB, defaultTableName string) string {
        return tablePrefix + defaultTableName
    }

    db.SingularTable(true)
    db.DB().SetMaxIdleConns(10)
    db.DB().SetMaxOpenConns(100)
}

func CloseDB() {
    defer db.Close()
}
```

```
package models

type Tag struct {
    Model

    Name       string `json:"name"`
    CreatedBy  string `json:"created_by"`
    ModifiedBy string `json:"modified_by"`
    State      int    `json:"state"`
}

func GetTags(pageNum int, pageSize int, maps interface{}) (tags []Tag) {
    db.Where(maps).Offset(pageNum).Limit(pageSize).Find(&tags)

    return
}
```

/Database data information

[image]

My results

```
"lists":[{"id":1,"created_on":0,"modified_on":0,"name":"czxtable","created_by":"","modified_by":"","state":0}]
```

```
sql: Scan error on column index 2, name "created_on": converting driver.Value type time.Time ("2019-11-09 18:33:14.923411 +0000 +0000") to a int: invalid syntax
```

The above is a postgresql query error,

My database time field type "timestamp"

I am using "github.com/jinzhu/gorm" to query the database, but the query result is "0".

What should I do when I query, can I get the correct time format?

ps:https://gorm.io/docs/connecting_to_the_database.html

There is only mysql processing, but there is no postgresql processing.

Sorry, give you more trouble, thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you show the definition of the `Tag` struct?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your reply, I edited the question, I am learning, there may be a wrong place, I can't find it, can you help me see the error?

Comment: You also need to show `Model` since the problem is with `created_on` which is not present *directly* in `Tag`.

Comment: The question has been edited, is the code you want? Thank you for your precious time.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that you're using `int` as the Go type for the timestamp fields. DB timestamps cannot be automatically decoded into an `int`. You should either use `time.Time` for you Go timestamp fields. Or you should change your DB column types from timestamp to integer. Or you need a custom Go `int` type that knows how to decode a DB timestamp.

Comment: If you take a look at the default `gorm.Model` type you can see that they also use `time.Time` for timestamp fields. https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html

Comment: Thank you very much, haha, my learning ability is not good enough, this is the result I got: {"code":200,"data":{"lists":[{"id":1,"created_on":"2019- 11-09T18:33:14.923411Z","modified_on":"2019-11-09T18:33:14.923411Z","name":"czxtable","created_by":"czx","modified_by":"", "state":1}],"total":1},"msg":"ok"}
How should I get a format like 2019-11-09T18:33:14? You are a good person

Comment: For that you'll need to declare a custom timestamp type and implement the `json.Marshaler` interface. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52445696/generic-approach-for-marshalling-a-structs-time-time-fields-to-json-with-custom. If you do that however it *might* break the encoding/decoding to/from the database, so you may need to have the custom timestamp also implement the `driver.Valuer` and `sql.Scanner` interfaces.

Comment: Thank you very much, I need to continue learning.