# How to omit time.Time value in golang when retrieving no rows from mysql?

Tags: mysql, go

As Reference MySQL database structure

```
id BIGINT
email string
password string
createdAt DATE
```

For example, when retrieving data `SELECT * FROM users` return no rows/values.

During the `rows.Scan()` values in Go, the createdAt values become scanned into `0001-01-01T00:00:00Z`.

My Question is how to make sure the return value is NULL like scanning string or int datatype?

Please ask further detail for any confusions.

Thank you.

It seems `omitempty` in `time.Time` datatype doesn't solve it.

I expect `{}` in the output. But got `{ createdAt : "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z" }`

Comment: Please show us how you are running `.Scan` and generating the output (include the `struct` definition). Generally you would detect that no rows were returned (either via `ErrNoRows` if using `QueryRow`, or by the fact that there are no rows returned by `Query`). In terms of values, the answers to one of these questions should help [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44670212/11810946), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28642838/11810946).

Comment: can you add your struct? where you defined data types?

Comment: `0001-01-01T00:00:00Z` is zero time in Go. PLease take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051973/what-is-the-zero-value-for-time-time-in-go

Comment: use `sql.NullTime` instead of `time.Time`